# Не работает background-repeat: repeat-y при двух колонках с разными float

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Сегодня столкнулся вот с такой проблемой.Если мы задаём что бы фоновое изображение растягивалось по Y и при этом у нас есть два блока первый content второй sidebar, с разными значениями float, тоесть у content - left, sidebar - right. То фоновое изображение не растягивается по y.
Ниже код:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="page_header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="page_footer"></div></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>

css

#page {background-image:url(images/middle.png); background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: repeat-y; margin:0 auto; padding-left: 60px; position: relative; width: 1024px;}
#content{ width:722px; float:left }
#sidebar{margin-right: 57px; width:244px; float:right}
```

Для примера что получается: 
http://s017.radikal.ru/i429/1112/94/8ae3153629c3.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При рендеринге #page высота не может быть расчитана, так как внутри находятся элементы с float. Чтобы заставить браузер корректно расчитать высоту контейнера нужно либо сделать float:left на сам контейнер, либо форсировать пересчет высоты через overflow:hidden, ну или выставить clear:both на #page_footer.

P.S. repeat-y не для расстягивания изображения, а для повтора по оси y.

Comment: Спасибо, решил по другому, но натолкнули правильно:)